# java 2D graphics library

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I'm looking for a java 2D graphics library for displaying node link diagrams (i.e. graphs). What I need:

1. add MouseListener to an element or similar functionality
2. highlight elements (redundant to 3 or 4)
3. show/hide elements
4. alter elements (thickness, color etc.)
5. automatic repainting
6. scaling/zooming, panning, rotating
7. nice to have: simple animation. Think of visualizing a force-based algorithm.
8. foss
9. rather simple, not necessarily a game engine
10. maintained/still developed ("alive")

I would probably use a quad tree, especially for efficient mouse enter/exit events. Anyway, a suitable solution should exist.

Some candidates:

- [G](http://geosoft.no/graphics/) - last version from 2009
- [Piccolo2D](http://www.piccolo2d.org/) - last version from 2011
- [jTem](http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jtem/java2d/) - last version from 2010
- processing - (not sure what this actually is)
- [pulpcore](https://code.google.com/p/pulpcore/) - discontinued
- [acm.graphics](http://jtf.acm.org/) - last version from 2006

Almost all are rather old. I'd prefer G, but the last version is from 2009.

Comment: - [G](http://geosoft.no/graphics/)
 - [Piccolo2D](http://www.piccolo2d.org/)
 - [jTem](http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jtem/java2d/)
 - [processing](http://processing.org/)
 - [pulpcore](code.google.com/p/pulpcore/)
 - [acm.graphics](jtf.acm.org/)

Comment: Have you looked at Java Graph (http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html)? I don't know much about it but thought I'd toss it on the table. Also, JGraphT (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jgrapht/) was updated in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Java Unified Network Graph (JUNG) framework.  It definitely meets criteria 1-9 on your list, comes with mouse event handling, but option 10 is a little fuzzy.  Version 2 is old (2010) but is stable enough that it's used in a number of corporate apps currently under development at my place of employment.

http://jung.sourceforge.net/

I believe someone is working on JUNG 3.0, but I'm not sure if it ever got off the ground.  At any rate, JUNG is definitely worth a look - highly extensible and comes with a lot of visualization and analysis algorithms baked in.